# SP2013/Display templates: Get index of current display template item?

Tags: display-template

I am using SharePoint 2013 and building display templates. I have now a control and item display template. In the control display template I can get the index of each item:

```
inCtx.CurrentItemIdx
```

But how can I do this in the item display template?

Answer (score 3):

The index can also be retrieved in the item display template the same way as the piece of code above:

```
ctx.CurrentItemIdx
```

In one of my blog posts is an example of how you could use it: [Showing Alternating Rows in the Content Search WebPart](http://www.eliostruyf.com/showing-alternating-rows-in-the-content-search-webpart-display-template/)